# TSQL for xml path - How can I include a subquery container element even if the subquery is empty?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

My query to build XML includes subqueries. The child records are supposed to go into a container element. The XML must have the container element even if there are no child records.

Consider the following. The `<Patients>` container element must exist even if there are no child records or validation fails.

```
<Hospital>
    <Patients>
        <Patient></Patient>
        <Patient></Patient>
        <Patient></Patient>
    </Patients>
</Hospital>
```

I've tried a couple of different approaches using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select
    (
        select
            PatientFields
        from
            PatientTable
        for xml path('Patient'), root('Patients'), elements xsinil, type
    )
for xml path('Hospital'), elements xsinil, type
```

The above approach leaves out the `<Patients>` element altogether for an empty set.

The one below includes the tag but adds the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute, which also causes validation to fail.

```
select
    (
        select
            PatientFields
        from
            PatientTable
        for xml path('Patient'), elements xsinil, type
    ) Patients
for xml path('Hospital'), elements xsinil, type
```

Is there any way to force the container element to be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    (
        select
            'John Doe'
        where 1 = 0
        for xml path('Patient'), type
    )
for xml path('Patients'), root('Hospital'), type
```